# import excel output sound?

Tags: matlab, math, matlab-deployment

I have a problem with Matlab - I need to do the following :

- Step 1 : Transceivers audio (Dave ',' Nick ',' Joe ',' Roy '.....) save as .wav
- Step 2 : Using matlab read file from .xls excel. (list of names)
- Step 3 : Use form data  step 2 .Output. wav or sound (the computer automatically read the list)

Can you for example show a segment of MATLAB code for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume you have some wav files ('Dave.wav', 'Nick.wav', 'Roy.wav', etc.). You have an excel file:
Dave,
Roy,
Dave,
Nick

And you want matlab to play (in this example), Dave.wav, then Roy.wav, then Dave.wav, then Nick.wav.

First, you need to read the xls file. I had trouble getting Matlab to do in; in principle, you can go file->import data, select the file, and then click 'generate code' on the next screen, and it will give you a function to import that kind of data. If it gives you an error, perhaps you can save the excel file as .csv instead, and repeat the same process.

Once you have a function `importfile`, you can do:

```
importfile('filename');
```

and the data will appear in a variable (probably the same as the file name - I will call it 'data' from now on).
then:

```
for i=1:numel(data)
  s = wavread([data{i} '.wav']);
  player = audioplayer(s, 22050);
  play(player); 
end
```